# Make a custom pie chart shape programmatically

Tags: android

I want to programmatically draw something to set it as a background of an `ImageView`. It should look like this:

[image]

So it's kinda like a pie chart but it is not a pie chart.

I found something to draw circles in circles:

```
    ShapeDrawable biggerCircle= new ShapeDrawable( new OvalShape());
    biggerCircle.setIntrinsicHeight( 60 );
    biggerCircle.setIntrinsicWidth( 60);
    biggerCircle.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, 60, 60));
    biggerCircle.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);

    ShapeDrawable smallerCircle= new ShapeDrawable( new OvalShape());
    smallerCircle.setIntrinsicHeight( 10 );
    smallerCircle.setIntrinsicWidth( 10);
    smallerCircle.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, 10, 10));
    smallerCircle.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
    smallerCircle.setPadding(50,50,50,50);
    Drawable[] d = {smallerCircle,biggerCircle};

    LayerDrawable composite1 = new LayerDrawable(d);

    btn.setBackgroundDrawable(composite1);
```

What i need is something to draw colored areas using a start degree and a end degree.

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the library https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart to achieve this.

Add below in xml:

```
 <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In java code:

```
PieChart chart = (Piechart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
```

Example code:

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/PieChartActivity.java

This is how it would look using it.

[image]